# At what temperature is bismuth the densest?

Tags: water, temperature, density

Both water and bismuth have denser liquids compared to solid forms, and we know water is the densest at the temperature of about 4°C.

Does the same thing apply to bismuth? Of course, I know the melting point of bismuth is about 271° C. So the temperature of interest should be around it I think.

Comment: The reasons that water has that density anomaly do not apply to bismuth. NIST has tabulated density values to peruse at your leisure.

Comment: So what's the reason for bismuth?

Comment: I guess I'm a bit confused - do you mean the liquid being denser than the solid, or that water is densest at about 4C?

Comment: Both. And in the case of bismuth it's densest at about 310C based on the paper in Nilay Ghosh's answer. While in the case of antimony there's no such an anomaly but its liquid form is also denser.

Comment: For water at 4C, see https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/81756/why-is-density-of-water-maximum-at-4-degree-celsius/105390#105390. For the rest, you need to understand that thermal expansion coefficients of many (well, all really) materials are not a constant and can even change sign. Why? the shape of the potential well the atoms find themselves in.

Comment: If all materials have a non-constant thermal expansion coefficients then why do most materials have a denser solid?

Comment: Density change on a phase change does not correlate with thermal expansion coefficients of a specific phase. But, at a high level, atoms in liquids want to move around so need more elbow room. Note that Bi (and Si, Ge, Sb, ...) are not close packed crystals. Si goes from a 4-fold coordinated semiconducting diamond cubic solid to an 8-fold coordinated metallic liquid. That one is easy to see how it could happen.

Answer (score 4):

> The densities of Sb and Bi melts were investigated by an improved Archimedean method. The results show that the density of the Sb melt decreases linearly with increasing temperature, but the density of the Bi melt firstly increases and then decreases as the temperature increases. **There is a maximum density value of $\pu{10.002 g/cm^3}$ at 310 ℃ ,about 39 ℃ above the melting point.** The temperature dependence of the Sb melt is well fitted with the expression $\pu{ρ = 6.8590 - 5.8105 × 10^{-4} T}$ , and that of the Bi melt is fitted with $\ce{ρ 
> = 10.3312 - 1.18 ×10^{-3} T}$.
>
> [image]

**Source**: Geng, Haoran & Sun, Chunjing & Wang, Rui & Qi, Xiaogang & Zhang, Ning. (**2007**). Temperature dependence of densities of Sb and Bi melts. Chinese Science Bulletin. 52. 2031-2034. DOI: [10.1007/s11434-007-0309-7](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/250967482_Temperature_dependence_of_densities_of_Sb_and_Bi_melts)

Also see:

1. Greenberg, Y. & Yahel, Eyal & Caspi, E. & Benmore, Chris & Beuneu, B. & Dariel, M.P. & Makov, Guy. (**2009**). Evidence for a temperature-driven structural transformation in liquid bismuth. EPL (Europhysics Letters). 86. 36004. DOI: [10.1209/0295-5075/86/36004.](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/231109934_Evidence_for_a_temperature-driven_structural_transformation_in_liquid_bismuth)
2. Tournier, R.F. Multiple Glass Transitions in Bismuth and Tin beyond Melting Temperatures. Metals **2022**, 12, 2085. DOI: [10.3390/met12122085](https://www.mdpi.com/2075-4701/12/12/2085)

Comment: Why does [this](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/circ/nbscircular382.pdf) say the density of liquid bismuth is 10.067 g/cm$^3$ which is bigger than 10.002? Also, there is [another](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/002219026380233X#:~:text=The%20density%20of%20liquid%20bismuth%20is%2010%C2%B7022%20g%2Fcm,cubical%20expansion%20coefficients%20were%20calculated.) article saying the number as 10.022.

Comment: @SnackExchange You should check latest papers which has improved measurement techniques. Density of bismuth around melting point is just above 9.9 g/cm3 which goes to maximum value of 10.002 g/cm3 at around 310 C (the ref.2 has a better graph). The Wikipedia article needs to have the values corrected.

Comment: When I plugged temperatures in the density formula of bismuth, I found the temperature should be about 280 K in order to have a density of about 10 g/cm$^3$. But when we put 583 K (310 C) the answer is about 9.6! How can it be explained?

Comment: @SnackExchange If you follow the paper, it says that in the range of m.p. and 310 C, the equation is $\mathrm{ρ = 9.44903+1.73×10^{−3} T}$ giving density value within 1.3% error. Above 310 C, the equation is $\mathrm{ρ =10.3312−1.18×10^{−3} T}$